# How to Loop Through ths Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm new to Javascript and I am begining to learn.

I need help understanding; how can I retrieve each carachter of this array.

```
var possibleRaysPasswords =['mobleyAndTrentonAreDead','tyrellIsElliot','dreadPirateRoberts'];
```

Like in these example:

```
 e.g: femtocell
 f
 fe
 fem
 femt
 femto
 femtoc
 femtoce
 femtocel
 femtocell
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes I know how to use it, but to retrieve intire elements, not every single character, like in the example.

Comment: Strings are accessible like an array. Use one loop to get each element, then another loop to get each character of the string.

Comment: This has already been answered,please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: This has already been answered,please check the link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get each character of each element, you may do a simple array transformation to get you an array of all the characters in all the items:

```
var allOfThem = arr.join('').split('');
```

That is: you first join all the elements into a single string. and then you split this string into array of characters. Then you can loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of what you've tried so far? Doing so will help us to answer any confusion you have.

For a start, let's demonstrate how to loop through each element in the array. We can declare an array the way you demonstrated:

```
var myArray = ["elements", "are", "pretty", "cool! "];
```

To loop through this array, we can simply use a for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);    // this provides the element at the ith index of the array
}
```

This will log, in order:

```
elements
are
pretty
cool!
```

You can access the individual characters of a string in the same exact way that you access individual elements of an array. Try that and see if you can get to where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two nested loop, one for the array and one for the atrings for the letters in combination with [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```js
var possibleRaysPasswords =['mobleyAndTrentonAreDead','tyrellIsElliot','dreadPirateRoberts'],
    i, j;

for (i = 0; i < possibleRaysPasswords.length; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= possibleRaysPasswords[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(possibleRaysPasswords[i].slice(0, j));
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if something is unclear. The comments in the code should tell you what's going on though:

```
// making this a constant, because we only want to read from this data
const passwords = ['mobleyAndTrentonAreDead', 'tyrellIsElliot', 'dreadPirateRoberts'];

// somewhat recently, we can also define functions like this
const printPassword = password => {
  // this function prints out the password starting from the first character, all the way to its end
  // if the password is 'test', the output should be 't te tes test'

  let resultString = ''; // this will be returned later
  // let's use the good old for loop
  // start at the first character (zero-indexed), and use the counter variable i to mark the end of the substring
  for (let i=1; i <= password.length; i++) {
    resultString += password.substring(0, i) + ' ';
  }
  return resultString;
};

// iterating over every password in the passwords array,
// and log the returned string to the console
passwords.forEach(password => console.log(printPassword(password)));
```

Answer (score 0):

user 'forEach' to iterate elements of array and 'substr' to part of string:

```
var possibleRaysPasswords =['mobleyAndTrentonAreDead','tyrellIsElliot','dreadPirateRoberts'];
possibleRaysPasswords.forEach(function(element){
   for(var i=0 ; i<element.length ; i++){
       console.log(element.substr(0,i));
   }
});
```

'for of' can also be used for iteration:

```
for (element of possibleRaysPasswords){
   for(var i=0 ; i<element.length ; i++){
       console.log(element.substr(0,i));
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As simple as that:

```
var letters = [];
for(let i of possibleRaysPasswords ){letters.push.apply(letters,i.split(""))}
console.log(letters);
```

That will create and array with all letters. Not sure if that was the question though

Comment: 1. From his comment, this doesn't seem to answer the question. 2. You should explain your code. This is a very incomplete answer as is.

Comment: I have change the console.log for a more complete answer